# Flowplayer 5.1.1 video width

Tags: jquery, html5-video, flowplayer

I have downloaded and inserted in my website the flowplayer ver. 5.1.1.

```
<script src="_scripts/flowplayer/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="_scripts/flowplayer/flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.417">
   <video poster="files/poster.png">
       <source type="video/webm" src="files/video.webm"/>
       <source type="video/mp4" src="files/video.mp4"/>
       <source type="video/ogv" src="files/video.ogv"/>
   </video>
</div>
```

The player and the video is OK! If i click on it it plays!
The only thing is that the player is bigger than the container div.

How can i change the player width?
I tried with css but with no results. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify it on the containing div.

```
<div class="flowplayer" 
    data-swf="https://<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];?>/flowplayer5/flowplayer.swf" 
    data-ratio="0.5265" 
    style="width:<?=$width;?>px;height:432px;">
```